# EF6 DB First Pre-Generated Views difficulties

Tags: entity-framework-6

The 50 seconds it takes EF to complete it's first query (as compared to milliseconds for the same or similar queries when it's warm) is making my MVC website look bad. I really need to get pre-compiled views working.

I have tried the power tools but when I run 'Generate Views' the VS12 output window shows

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities.EdmxUtility.GetMappingCollectionEF6(Assembly ef6Assembly, String& containerName)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.OptimizeContextHandler.OptimizeEdmx(String inputPath)
```

The T4 templates that can generate views seem to be for code first only.

How can I get power tools working or is there another way to pre-generate the Views?